# I'm trying to get the positive solutions to the following system of linear equations

Tags: r, linear-algebra

```
5.1x + 15y +z = 280
6.9x + 17y +z = 320
5.3x + 13y +z = 270
```

I am particularly interested in solutions where x >= 30
I have done the following but I would like to get the other solutions

```
 A <- rbind(c(5.1, 15, 1),  
           c(6.9, 17, 1),  
           c(5.3, 13, 1)) 
 B <- c(280, 320, 270) 
 solve(A, B)
```

Comment: A is invertible, so there's only one solution.

Comment: A is full rank, thus giving an unique solution which is not controlled by your condition `x>=30`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no opportunity to control the solution once you have a unique solution since `A` is full rank.

However, if you remove the last equation from your system, say, `AA <- A[-3, ]` and `BB <- B[-3]`, then `AA` becomes ***rank deficient***, and you will have room to add the constraint `x>=30` to achieve one solution.

---

For example, given `AA` and `BB` like below

```
AA <- A[-3, ]
BB <- B[-3]
```

we can make a random `x>=30` like `aux <- 30 + abs(rnorm(1))`., and solve the problem

```
> solve(rbind(AA, c(1, rep(0, ncol(AA) - 1))), c(BB, aux))
[1]  30.787640  -7.708876 238.616173
```